# Positioning a child block in the center of the parent block in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a parent and it has icons with text that I distributed using display: flex, but now the problem is. How do I make a block with icons in the center of the parent? I tried different ways that I found on the Internet, but they don't work as I understand because of display: flex

```css
.icons {
  margin: auto 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="service">
  <div class="icons">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
    <img src="#">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "they don't work" is not a helpful problem statement. How don't they work? Any specific error messages? Unexpected behavior (describe)?

Answer (score -3):

Your CSS value `justify-content: space-between;` was wrong for aligning it in center.

```css
.icons {
  margin: auto 250px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center; /* you gave this wrong value */
  align-items: center;
}


/* Demo */

img {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.service {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="service">
  <div class="icons">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Commenting on downvotes is absolutely [**not** required](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin). But I suspect your answer was downvoted because it isn't clear how this solves the OP's problem (especially given that it isn't entirely clear what their problem is in the first place).

Comment: The question was " How do I make a block with icons in the center of the parent?" - I added the answer. He's code was incorrect